# Carry page values to another model page, Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I want to carry notebook page One2many field to another model page.

[image]

These field from my main model. I want to carry page field with this operation.

T
[image]

How can fill these page fields after creating method.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Brother, Please state your question clearly**.

I hope that notebook has a one2many relation with the purchase ?

If so, Before that you have to know in which `purchase order id` you want to add those field values.

Then create a object button in your custom model, use create method in that and in the dictionary pass the same `purchase order id` in that.